# Incrementing a long value which is a date

Tags: java, calendar

I am having a long value which represents a date ,that is have converted a date to long,now i want to increment the long value itself to next date,how to perform operation on a long value to get the next date.

```
long endDate=1454756400000
```

represent todays date long value,which is milliseconds  (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970).

Comment: Why don't you use the date and increment the date by one day? That's exactly what they are supposed to be used for.

Comment: Is that a number of seconds representing the date?

Comment: What's next date? Next milli? next hour? next day? next week? If you want the next day, simply add: 1000 * 3600 * 24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the representation?  Seconds since some epoch?

If seconds, you can add seconds per day (60*60*24)?  Then covert back to printable.

Comment: which is milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970).

Comment: How about planned leap seconds?

Comment: Java time format doesn't have leap seconds. Every day has the same number of seconds.

Comment: @esej What is the algorithm for leap seconds?  Leap years are easy, but isn't it a manual adjustment when leap seconds are added (or removed) by the 'time lords'?

Comment: @Neil Yes, I was/am under the impression thoose manual seconds/etc are included in JRE releases. I can't speak to how good "they" are at keeping track of them before they happen, or that they really are.

Comment: @Neil how about previous date? how to handle this to get previous date?

Answer (score 2):

You use the Calendar class

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
rightNow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //add one day

long nextDayInMillis = rightNow.getTimeInMillis()
```

Java API for Calendar:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Answer (score 2):

1 day = 86 400 000 ms

Therefore:

```
final long DAY_TO_MS = 86400000;
long today = 1454756400000;

long tomorrow = today + DAY_TO_MS;
```

Answer (score 1):

long longvalue = ...;

java.util.Date dateValue = new java.util.Date(longvalue);

Now, you can increment the date and then convert it back to long.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want :

```
long endDate=1454756400000L;
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(new Date(endDate));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime().getTime());
```

That will add 1 day to the date and output the corresponding long time

Answer (score 1):

You could use java's calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(<YourLongValue>);
```

and then add:

```
calender.add(Calendar.DAY, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long endDate=1454756400000L;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(endDate));;
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
long newEndDate = newDate.getTime();
```

Using a fixed long value for how long a day is will miss leap seconds (and other corner cases).